# Can I see the category of objects over $X$ as a quotient?

Tags: category-theory, quotient-spaces

I'm learning about the category of objects over an object $X$. The definition is simple enough, for a category $\mathcal{C}$ and an object $X$ in it define the category $\mathcal{C}/X$ whose objects consist of the morphisms $Y\rightarrow X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ with the obvious morphisms between objects.

The notation seems to suggest that this should be a sort of "quotient". I wanted to check my intuition against this:

- If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ then the ideals of $R/I$ are in bijection with the ideals of $R$ containing $I$.

So if we only care about ideals the quotient $R/I$ consists of all ideals over $I$, so I imagine one could define an arrow $J\rightarrow I$ if and only if $I\subseteq J$. This however seems a bit artificial because I am taking the arrows to be what I need.

Hopefully my question won't be too vague - Here it goes: Is there a nice (general) way to interpret the category of objects over $X$ as a quotient in some category? I am particularly interested on how it would work with quotient topological spaces!

Comment: You should not read too much into the notation here. Alternate notations include $\mathcal{C}_{/ X}$, $\mathcal{C} \downarrow X$, (and getting obscure here) $\mathcal{C}^X$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The similarity to quotient notation is essentially entirely coincidental here.  The motivation is that you are just considering objects "over" $X$ and so you write the category by putting $\mathcal{C}$ "over" $X$.  The use of the $/$ symbol is kind of a pun here, conflating this notion of "over" with the entirely unrelated notion of "over" as in division.